# Google plus API's to get company page's +1 count

Tags: google-plus, google-plus-one

Is there a google plus API to pull company page's +1 count?
eg company page: https://plus.google.com/111883881632877146615/posts

I want to get the +1 count(followers of a company page) through API. We can get a badge from here developers.google.com/+/plugins/badge/ which provides this information but can we get this from API? I dont think we can scrape it either because its generated from javascript

Please see the image:
http://syumus.com/linkedin/gpluscount.png

Can we make a API call for this?

Answer (score 3):

There's no supported API that provides this number. If you'd like to display it on your page, you must use the Google+ badge from your screen shot.

There's an [open request](http://code.google.com/p/google-plus-platform/issues/detail?id=57) for an API that provides this data. If you star the issue, you'll be notified when it's updated.